# How to include chain.cer in a keystore file?

Tags: linux, ssl-certificate, keytool, keystore

I would like to create a keystore file with a certificate and a chain.cer file.

```
# openssl pkcs12 -export -chain -CAfile chain.cer -in example.cer -inkey example.key -out keystore.jks -name tomcat -passout pass:changeit
Error unable to get issuer certificate getting chain.
```

**Question**

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keytool` is the command you are looking for to work with Java keystore files.  It is provided by the [Java JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).  *(You might be able to do it with `openssl`, but I am not aware of it.)*

And to import a root or intermediate CA certificate into a keystore:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file cachain.crt -keystore keystore.jks
```

For more information and examples:
[The Most Common Java Keytool Keystore Commands](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html)

Comment: `keytool` looks very interesting. When I do this, Internet Explorer can still not see the chain cert. Works in FF and Chrome though.

Comment: Interesting. Try adding the individual certificates instead of a chain? Sounds like an IE problem at that point.

Comment: Correction. Just tried with FF on Windows. It also thinks the certificate is untrusted.

Comment: How do I "add the individual certificates?

Comment: Instead of importing one chain cert, source the certificates (from the issuer) which make up the chain.  Refer to the examples in the link above.